# 2-3x increase in peers banned by bitcoind

Tags: bitcoind

In the last week, with no changes to my node's configuration, I've noticed my node is auto-banning peers at 2-3 times the rate of before. Where usually I'd have 25-30 peers banned every 24 hours, the rate has jumped to 100/day. All the bans are auto-generated by bitcoind 0.19.1, the node simply reports 'peer misbehaving' or something similar. I do not bandwidth limit my node.

Any insight as to what's causing the banned nodes?

Can this be a result of increased interest in bitcoin and more people bootstrapping nodes? I don't see nodes that are hogging a lot of bandwidth, so this doesn't seem true on the surface.

Any suggestions how to look into the increase in misbehaving nodes?

Comment: debug.log output would be useful for figuring out what's going on.

Comment: Nothing unusual, then usual reports about new blocks and connected/disconnected nodes. Note that my node still has a normal (100+) number of peers, but now the number of banned peers has increased, indicating an increase the gross number of connections to my node